# Convert date field into text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file which has a column formatted as date in the format `dd-mm-YYYY`.

I need to convert that field to text. If I change the field type excel converts it to a strange value (like `40603`).

I tried the text function but it gives me Error 508.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean convert to text? You want to have your date appear in a different format? (40603 is the number of days since 1900)

Comment: I need to concatenate that date with other text in a formula I have. But when i select the field where the date is in the formula it doesn´t put the date(23-04-2012) but the converted value. I want it to keep the date as string.

Answer (score 69):

You don't need to convert the original entry - you can use TEXT function in the concatenation formula, e.g. with date in A1 use a formula like this

`="Today is "&TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yyyy")`

You can change the "dd-mm-yyyy" part as required

Comment: I got error501 when applying =TEXT(D2,"dd-mm-yyyy") where D2 as the value 18-03-2011 formatted as a date

Comment: I don't know what that error means - depending on your location you might need semi-colon in place of comma like `="Today is "&TEXT(A1;"dd-mm-yyyy")` - and TEXT function is also region-specific so you need to use exactly the same format in the TEXT function as you would in your formatting

Answer (score 26):

You can use `TEXT` like this as part of a concatenation

`=TEXT(A1,"dd-mmm-yy") & " other string"`

[image]

Answer (score 18):

If that is one table and have nothing to do with this - the simplest solution can be copy&paste to notepad then copy&paste back to excel :P

Comment: just before pasting back to excel make the target cells formatted as text

Comment: Copy&Paste ... incredible! Thank you, you've saved me from throwing the pc out of the window!