# Excel Macro to convert date value to plain text, no formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Similar question (but not the same) as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992893/convert-date-field-into-text-in-excel).

My question is slightly different.  I have a column of dates converted from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Ex:

> 2013-11-04
>   2013-11-05
>   2013-12-10

These cells are formatted with the following type: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I'm having an issue conforming to an XML Schema and then exporting to XML. I think the issue is related to the cells formula (seems to work when there is no formula), therefore I'd like to keep the text only and remove the formatting.

There is a `Clear > Clear Formats` option but that converts the date back to it's original state `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I also need to do this in a Macro.

Here my pseudo code:

```
For Each cell In myRange
    Dim s As String
    s = c.Text
    c.ClearFormats
    c.Text = s
Next
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't... I get an `object required` error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at least the correct syntax:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim Myrange As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim s As String
    Set Myrange = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each Cell In Myrange
        s = Cell.Text
        Cell.ClearFormats
        Cell.Value = s
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

but you might **actually need**:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim Myrange As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim s As String
    Set Myrange = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each Cell In Myrange
        s = Cell.Text
        Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
        Cell.Value = s
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

do it with little tricky ..like below

```
For Each Cell In myrange
    Dim s As String
    s = "'" & Cell.Text
    Cell.ClearFormats
    Cell.Value = s
Next
```