# How do I keep the date in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I'm attempting to create a date range in a merged cell with the following:

```
=(A1-1) & "-" & (A1-6)
```

So I'm referencing a date that I have in a cell (A1) and subtracting a few days from it. Once I try to do this it returns the following:

```
41914-41909
```

I'd like to be able to keep the dates in the following format:

```
1/1/2014 - 1/7/2014
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the dates to text before trying to concatenate them as a string.

```
=TEXT(A1-1, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " - " & TEXT(A1-6, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Here's a similar question on StackOverflow: [Convert date field into text in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992893/convert-date-field-into-text-in-excel). It gives a little more detail if you have any problems.