# C# - Excel, converting date to string

Tags: c#, excel

I want to convert date to string in excel, i have similiar problem to this :

[Convert date field into text in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992893/convert-date-field-into-text-in-excel)

But I need to implement this in C# project, any idea how to achieve that ?

I had numbers in format like this : "1-2".

I also get strange number like 40530 after formating whole excel file to text, I think that's the number of days from year 1900.

**EDIT**:

I didn't mention that I'm reading data from .xml file, then fill excel file with this data, I had some columns that I fill with text like "1-2", but when I open excel it's shows as 2 January (excel changes it to date automatically).

**SOLUTION**

Maybe someone will use it:

```
 if (value != null)
   {
      if (value.Contains("-") && value.Length == 3)  // cause my value = "1-2"
        {
           value = "'" + value;    // addin ' to value
        }
   }                               //now value ="'1-2"
```

Where value is my cell that I'm writing to excel. The " ' " sign will guarantee that the value "1-2" will be displayed as text, not as date.

Comment: This sounds like you have a formatting issue

Comment: Please share your code. It's hard to help without looking at what you've done so far.

Comment: I tried :  Range cells = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1].Cells;
cells.NumberFormat = "@";